# Specific font_face based on syntax in Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, json, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is it possible to display a specific font_face for each individual syntax language setting in Sublime Text 2?  For example:

```
"php" : { "font_face" : "Droid Sans Mono" },
"c#" : { "font_face" : "Courier New" },
"javascript" : { "font_face" : "monospace" }
```

Couldn't find much about the font_face setting in ST2 other than how to change it globally.  My job requires me to jump around a lot of different language files and think this would make them easier to distinguish on the fly.  I like my color scheme and want to keep that the way it is, but unfortunately it doesn't quite differ enough for me to be able to pick out the languages quickly.

Comment: You might try posting this on SuperUser, they might have a better answer. (particularly because sublimetext doesn't appear to have many followers on SO)

Comment: Saddens me to hear about the no ST followers...  But thank you for the tip! I'll go post there now.

Comment: if you mouseover the tags (e.g. "sublimetext") it'll show you the # of followers for the tag.

Comment: And that's why I love the StackNetwork, learn something new every time I look at it.  Thank you again!

Comment: In case people are interested, I've posted an answer over at http://superuser.com/questions/465661/specific-font-face-based-on-syntax-in-sublime-text-2/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For syntax specific settings for targeted language, in `Packages > User` folder, create a file with name of that language.

ex. for `PHP`, create `php.sublime-settings`.

and add following code to it:

```
{
    "font_face": "Source Code Pro"
}
```

For `JavaScript` create file names `JavaScript.sublime-settings` and so on.

Also, using this technique, you can set different color schemes for different languages using the `color_scheme` attribute.

```
{
    "font_face": "Source Code Pro",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Flatland/Flatland Monokai.tmTheme"
}
```

Alternatively, if the file with targeted language is open, you can go to `Preferences > Settings - More > Syntax Specific - User`, and add the `font_face` setting.

Comment: What about different font faces for a specific syntax? For example I want to have italic version of my font to be used for comment lines? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

If you go to `Preferences > Settings - More > Syntax Specific - User`, you can add

```
{
    "font_face": "Source Code Pro"
}
```

to have that font for only that syntax.

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, to configure a certain syntax you must first have a file of that syntax open.

Comment: People are searching around the internet to find this comment ^^.